# how to change the scriplet to JSTL display string array

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

how to change the scriplet to JSTL

```
    <%String sentenceArray[] = (String[])request.getAttribute("displaySentenceArray"); %> 

<% for (int i=0; i< sentenceArray.length;i++){ %>

    <p> The Result IS   : <%=sentenceArray[i] %>  </p>

<%} %>
```

I am new to JSTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSTL should look like this

```
    <c:forEach var="sentence" items="${requestScope.displaySentenceArray}" >
        <p> The Result IS   :<c:out value="${sentence}"></c:out></p>
    </c:forEach>
```

Here requestScope.displaySentenceArray will get the whole array from request.'sentence'will be a single element of array, `<c:forEach>` tag will iterate the array and `<c:out>` will print the element to JSP.